# http authentication, php 5.3

Tags: php, http-authentication

I like this simple http authenticating for some non-critical pages.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  echo 'Text, der gesendet wird, falls der Benutzer auf Abbrechen drückt';
  exit;
} else {
  echo "<p>Hallo {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
  echo "<p>Sie gaben {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} als Passwort ein.</p>";
}
?>
```

Now I am trying to implement it on server with php 5.3 and it doesnt work.
Whats wrong?

I type name and password, press enter and pages show me dialog again.
No values in $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'].

Comment: Is PHP running as an Apache module?

Comment: "It doesn't work." isn't a clear description of what went wrong.

Comment: why don't u put in your login, update the script to do a `var_dump($_SERVER);exit;`, then press submit?

Comment: This is the example code from http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php - you should also read the heaps of examples, particularly the ones involving HTTP_AUTHORIZATION and REDIRECT_ variables, which can be set alternatively (depending on PHP SAPI and Apache config).

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem. According to me service provider, this is an old version of php that doesn't work on php 5.5 & higher. You will have to find a newer version of php.

Comment: (To the nay-sayers, this IS an answer.  He's saying that a possible solution is to upgrade.  Now this may or may not make sense, but it is a genuine attempt at an answer ... IMO.)

Comment: I am facing the same issue after modifying the httpd.conf file for reverse  proxy.

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTTP Authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) page on php.net:

> As of PHP 4.3.0, in order to prevent someone from writing a script
>   which reveals the password for a page that was authenticated through a
>   traditional external mechanism, the PHP_AUTH variables will not be set
>   if external authentication is enabled for that particular page and
>   safe mode is enabled. Regardless, REMOTE_USER can be used to identify
>   the externally-authenticated user. So, you can use
>   $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].

Perhaps this applied to this case. (just noticed this is an old question :)